# Exploded deployment fails on JBoss 5

Tags: deployment, jboss, jboss5.x, ear, exploded

I have a web application which deploys fine as an ear file. But when I try to deploy it in exploded form it fails like this:

```
17:13:17,305 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Start: name=persistence.unit:unitName=app.ear/#app-persistence state=Create
java.lang.RuntimeException: could not find relative path: lib/persistence-jpa.jar
    at org.jboss.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitDeployment.getRelativeURL(PersistenceUnitDeployment.java:208)
    at org.jboss.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitDeployment.start(PersistenceUnitDeployment.java:267)
.
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not find child 'lib/persistence-jpa.jar' on 'FileHandler@4348388[path= context=file:/home/petteri/bin/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/standard/deploy/ real=file:/home/petteri/bin/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/standard/deploy/]'
    at org.jboss.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitDeployment.getRelativeURL(PersistenceUnitDeployment.java:203)
```

The persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<persistence
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="app-persistence">
        <jta-data-source>java:/app</jta-data-source>
        <jar-file>lib/persistence-jpa.jar</jar-file>
        <properties>

 ... some hibernate stuff ...

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your server directory structure. You should have deploy/lib/persistance-jpa.jar/ in order for this to work.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not find child 'lib/persistence-jpa.jar' on
     'FileHandler@4348388[path= context=file:/home/petteri/bin/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/standard
    /deploy/ real=file:/home/petteri/bin/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/standard/deploy/]'
```

is saying that that file/directory is not found..

Comment: Hmm, true - I modified the persistence.xml to have <jar-file>app.ear/lib/persistence-jpa.jar</jar-file> and now it works. I assumed that the lookup would happen inside the exploded ear directory.

Answer (score -1):

Directory structure should be:

EAR 
    - warfile.WAR 
    - lib 
           -  persistence-jpa.jar
            -  The other jar file which contain persistence.xml
    - enterpricejavabean.ejb

persistace.xml file jar element should be  <jar-file>../lib/persistence-jpa.jar</jar-file>